# Does CouchDB have a "bulk get all revisions" feature?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using CouchDB with PouchDB and have noticed that remote-remote replication (or replication to PouchDB) does a lot of

`/db/doc?revs=true&open_revs=all&attachments=true&_nonce=...`

Do any of CouchDB's bulk APIs fetch the revs and open_revs (`revs=true&open_revs=all`) of more than one document at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your issue on GitHub as well.  This is really something that would be better to ask in the CouchDB mailing list or #couchdb on IRC.

If you do `all_docs` with `keys`, you can actually get the most recent revision information even for deleted documents, but for more than one revision, I don't think so.

If what you're really asking is whether we've gotten replication in PouchDB to go about as fast as it can go given the current CouchDB replication protocol, I think the answer is yes. :)

Comment: The touchdb documentation, sadly the best replication protocol documentation for couchdb, also notes the lacking api. Time to learn some Erlang...

Comment: n/m, I found it. I also got inspired and wrote a bit about our new replication algorithm [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/340cb898f8ed9f3db8a0) (where you can find a link to the TouchDB article).